# How to access integrated switch module of a Cisco 3850 Router

Tags: cisco

I have a Cisco 3850 Switch with the 48-port switch addon module.  Both the router and the switch have a IP address and telnet enabled, but telnet recently stopped working on the switch module.  I can get into the Router interface via telnet.  Once I'm in, how can I switch over to the switch module without telnet responding on that interface?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer at http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/access/interfaces/software/feature/guide/eesm_sw.html

Basically you need to get into enable mode on the router, then run the

```
service-module gigabitethernet2/0 session
```

command, where the "gigabitethernet2/0" part corresponds to one of the interfaces in this command:

```
sh ip interface brief
```

in my case it was the GigabitEthernet2/0 interface (identified by the NVRAM "method" parameter)

```
c3825#sh ip interface brief
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0         XX.XX.XX.118   YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/1         XX.XX.XX.122   YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet2/0         XX.XX.XX.199   YES NVRAM  up                    up
```